# Merging local account with social auth

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0

My site offers local authentication (email + password) and social auth (facebook, google, etc).

There's 2 users: Alice (malicious) and Bob (good).

Alice creates an account using local authentication. She uses Bob's email. Her account looks like this in the DB:

```
email: 'bob@bob.com'
password: 'hunter2'
isEmailVerified: false
```

Now, Bob joins my site. He joins via google's oauth 2. Since his email already exists in the DB, we verify it & his google info is attached to the account:

```
email: bob@bob.com
password: 'hunter2'
isEmailVerified: true
googleAuth: {
  name: 'Bob smith'
}
```

Now, Alice has access to Bob's account, uh oh!

Obviously this is wrong. But what's a better way of going about it *without requiring email verification before account creation*? Is it possible? I'm sure this has already been solved in the wild, but I can't figure out how to do it without impacting the user experience.

Options that I came up with, but they seem wrong:

- Delete Alice's account if the email isn't verified & create a new, separate account for Bob
- Disallow Bob from joining because his email is already in use
- Remove the password from the account so Alice can't log in
- Don't create accounts until the email is verified (not user friendly)

Comment: So how can you trust some info (email) if you haven't check its authenticity? What is the point in using an identifier called "email" if it's not proven to be a valid one?

Comment: That's exactly right, but the vast majority of sites I visit allow me to create an account without first verifying my email. I'm curious, how do they handle this?

Comment: how about telling the user that there's an user using that email account then show him the username of the account which has his email in use and an option to choose like "not you?" and if he clicks it let him be able to verify his email and if he does verify the email then delete the mailicious account.

Comment: @ivan I like this, but I don't have a username field, so I'd have to provide Bob with another piece of Alice's personal information. Not sure if this is ok...

Comment: i dont really think thats ok, soo instead of providing the username how about just showing him the email account one more time just to make sure and if he claims that's his email account then let him try to verify it if he does verify it let him change the password of the account

Comment: But by using google oauth, we already know 100% that Bob is the verified owner of that email, so there's no reason to ask him if it's his, right? Then the question is whether or not to just delete the account that Alice made.

Comment: then, provide him info about when was the account made and ask him for permission to delete this account. (or just provide him as much info as possible avoiding personal information or just ask for his permission to delete that account)

Answer (score 1):

Before marking the account as verified, make the user enter his password. As Bob doesn't know Alice's password, he must have his password resetted.

Comment: This would work, but requires that Bob enter his password twice (once in the google oauth & again back on my site). Then if he doesn't know the password, the account is essentially deleted, since we don't want to transfer over any info that might be from Alice, right?

Comment: Remember that if Alice did identify herself with Bob's email, Bob's identity is stolen, the extra password in your app would be a security enhancement